# Solving differential equation using Wronski.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say we have $$x^2y''-xy'-3y=-3x^2.$$
The solution of the homogeneuous equation
$$x^2y''-xy'-3y=0$$ is
$y_H = A x^{3} + B x^{-1}$, where we set $y_1 = x^3$ and $y_2 = x^{-1}.$

Then we start searching the particular solution using the form $y_P = A(x) x^{3} + B(x) x^{-1}.$
By the Wronski determinant we have
$$A' = -\frac{y_2 f}{W} \quad \text{and} \quad B' = \frac{y_1 f}{W}.$$

We continue:
$W = y_1 y_2' - y_2 y_1' = x^3(-x^{-2}) - x^{-1}3x^2 = -4x$
$$A' = -\frac{-x^{-1}3x^2}{-4x}=-3/4 \quad \text{and} \quad B' = \frac{-3x^3x^2}{-4x} = \frac{3}{4}x^4.$$
We therefore have, by integration, $A=-\frac{3}{4}x$ and $B=\frac{3}{20}x^5$.
We finally get $y_P = -\frac{3}{5}x^4.$
But this is not a solution. Why?

Comment: Still looking through to try to find an error, but just wanted to mention that you can get an answer more easily using method of undetermined coefficients, assume $y_p = Ax^2$ and you should have a pretty easy time. (Edit: found the error, writing answer now)

Answer (score 1):

The solution method you used is specifically for equations of the form $y'' + q(x)y' + r(x)y = g(x),$ so specifically where the coefficient on the second derivative is $1.$ Here, our coefficient is $x^2,$ so we divide through by $x^2$ to get our equation in the form $y'' - \frac1{x}y' - \frac3{x^2}y = -3.$ This will not change your answers for the homogeneous case so we can now proceed with the Wronskian method:

$$A' = -\frac{x^{-1} \cdot -3}{-4x} = -\frac{3}{4x^2},\ \ \  B' = \frac{x^3 \cdot -3}{-4x} = \frac{3}{4}x^2$$

Now integrating we get:
$$A = \frac{3}{4x},\ \ \  B = \frac14x^3$$

And plugging these in we now have:
$$y_p = \frac{3}{4x} \cdot x^3 + \frac14x^3 \cdot \frac1{x} = x^2$$

---

For future reference, specifically with this type of equation we can pretty easily obtain this result using the method of undetermined coefficients. Since we get a polynomial at the end and the order of the polynomial doesn't change when we feed it through the left-hand-side, we know our solution has to be of the form $y_p = Ax^2.$ Differentiating we get $y_p' = 2Ax, y_p'' = 2A.$ Plugging these in, we get

$$2Ax^2 - x(2Ax) - 3(Ax^2) = -3x^2 \Rightarrow -3Ax^2 = -3x^2$$

Setting the coefficients equal on both sides yields $-3A = -3$ or simply $A = 1,$ so $y_p = x^2.$

Hope this helps!